# imagick php extension fails to load

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, web-server

I can't seem to get `Imagick` to work.

I have PHP Version 5.2.8 installed (`php-fpm` used toghether with `nginx`).

I have installed the latest ImageMagick from source.

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.5-1 2009-08-25 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

I have installed `imagick` with the `pecl` installer:

```
$ pecl list
Package Version State
imagick 2.3.0   stable
```

When I try to restart the php server, I get:

`Starting php_fpm PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20060613/imagick.so' - /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block in Unknown on line 0`

I am running:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hardy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 8.04.2"
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you wanted to make it difficult on yourself and purposely avoid the Ubuntu packaging system?

```
jbouse@solitare:~$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jaunty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 9.04"
```

Then I installed: `aptitude install imagemagick`

```
jbouse@solitare:~$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.4.5 2009-06-04 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2008 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

Then for good measure: `aptitude install php5-imagick`

I now have a PHP page that watermarks my images on the fly for me and another one that allows me to upload and watermark them. I've written a Python script to submit all images in a directory to the form and save the watermarked versions in another directory.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid apt-get and that is how I installed both ImageMagick and Imagick until now, but I'm having problems with the 'quantizeImage' function and I need to upgrade (not sure which of them is causing the problems, but my guess is that it's ImageMagick)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was caused by a bug in `gcc 4.2`.
More information:
[mailing list discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/88a6c9d2613cdd4f/371fdea1ca118de7?lnk=raot&fwc=1) and
[bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+source/gcc-4.2/+bug/235070)

After recompiling ImageMagick with the `--disable-openmp` flag, imagick now loads fine.